# Addressing Reliable Output in Newspaper3k

Tags: python-3.x, anaconda, feed, miniconda

## Current Behavior:

In attempting to use the [News-aggregator package Newspaper3k](https://newspaper.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) , I am unable to produce consistent/reliable output.

## System/Environment Setup:

```
Windows 10
Miniconda3 4.5.12
Python 3.7.1
Newspaper3k 0.2.8
```

## Steps (Code) to Reproduce:

```
import newspaper

cnn_paper = newspaper.build('http://cnn.com')
print(cnn_paper.size())
```

## Expected Behavior/Output (varies based on current links posted on cnn):

Produce consistent number of posted links on cnn on consecutive Print output runs.

## Actual Behavior/Output

Running the code the first time produces a different number of links than code run immediately after.

```
1st Run Print output: 94 (as of time of posting this question)
2nd Run Print output: 0 
3rd Run Print output: 18
4th Run Print output: 7
```

Printing the actual links will vary the same way as the above link count print.  I have tried using a number of different news sources, and the same unexpected variance results.  Do I need to change my User-Agent Header?  Is this a detection issue?  How do I produce reliable results?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

My issue was resolved by better understanding of the default caching found under the heading [6.1.3 Article caching in the user documentation](https://media.readthedocs.org/pdf/newspaper/latest/newspaper.pdf) .

Apart from my general ignorance, my confusion came from the fact that the [read the docs 'Documentation' listed the caching function as a TODO as can be seen here](https://newspaper.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/advanced.html#caching)

Upon better scrutiny, I discovered:

> By default, newspaper caches all previously extracted articles
> andeliminates any article which it has already ex-tracted.This feature
> exists to prevent duplicate articles and to increase extraction speed.
>
> The return value of cbs_paper.size()changes from 1030 to 2 because
> when we first crawled cbs we found 1030 articles. However, on our
> second crawl, we eliminate all articles which have already been
> crawled. This means 2 new articles have been published since our first
> extraction.
>
> You may opt out of this feature with the
> memoize_articlesparameter.
> You may also pass in the lower
> level ‘‘Config‘‘ objects as covered in the advanced section.

```
>>>import newspaper
>>>cbs_paper = newspaper.build('http://cbs.com', memoize_articles=False)
>>>cbs_paper.size()1030
```